# MediaPlayer.start() dies from too much clicking

Tags: android

In Adnroid, at first i declare the mediaplayer by

```
MediaPlayer mpl;
```

next I have this in the onCreate method

```
mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hit );
mp.setVolume(1, 1);
```

and a function that's supposed to play a sound when called

```
public void click()
{
    mp.start();
}
```

yet the problem is that if the user calls this function multiple times, before it has stopped playing the last sound, it will die and stop playing any sounds, before the app is reset.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks!

**edit - found a solution:**

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mpl.release();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void click()
{
    if( ! mp.isPlaying() ) {
        mp.start();
    }//if
}//met
```

Answer (score 1):

you can disable the button.

or you can stop current playing and star

new in onClick()